# How do you print out a string that has each element of an array four to a line

Tags: java, arrays, methods, tostring

This is my code

```
public String toString() {
    String B = A[0] + " ";
    for (int w = 1; w < this.A.length; w-=-1) {
        B += A[w] + " ";
        if(w % 4 == 0)
            B += "\n";
    }
    return B;
}
```

I am trying to make a string that has each element of my array in it and after every fourth element a new line is added. The output should be something like this:

```
AA BB CC DD
EE FF GG HH
II JJ KK LL
MM NN OO PP
```

I am writing a toString method for a java class. The array has 52 elements
Instead I keep getting this as an output:

```
1S 4S 6S 2S 8S 
8S 7S 3S 7S 
6S 8S 5S 6S
3C 3C 1C 8C 
8C 9C 4C
```

Comment: `w-=-1` I mean yes, but that is an odd way to add one to `w`. What output do you get, what output do you expect?

Comment: Why this weird loop? Why doesn't `w` start from 0 and why do you use `w -= -1` instead of using `w++`?

Comment: What problem(s) do you have with this code?

Comment: No, don't add information in the comments. Instead, [edit] the question, add the information there - properly formatted - and use the comments only to let us know that you have added information to the question. Comments are not meant for code or formatted output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using StringBuilder:

```
private static void printArray(String[] array) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(i > 0 && i % 4 == 0) {
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        sb.append(array[i]);
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is:

```
String B = A[0] + " ";
for (int w = 1; w < this.A.length; w-=-1) {
    if (w % 4 == 0) {
        B += "\n";
    }
    // this line is after the check because you already added the first
    // element to the string before the loop
    B += A[w] + " ";
}
```

**Also**: Appending to a `String` in a loop is an expensive operation because Strings in java are immutable. Use `StringBuilder` instead. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1532547/8430155).

I do not understand `w-=-1` over `w++`.